# Add and remove data to a list PHP

Tags: php

I'm working on an application that uses some saved data to work with it later.
I can't use database so this have to be file based.

The thing works like this:

- A file name called hosts.txt that contains host:service on every line (diff hosts and services).
- My PHP file reads the txt line by line, splits by the delimiter ":" and makes a request with the data that has just recived.

Untill here, cool. I also have another file (a HTML form) that allows me to add that at the end of the file. But my problem is the next:

I want to be able to add and remove that from the file so when the next check is done (the check is made every 30 sec) the data should be updated.

Example:

host.txt contains this:

```
host1:service1
host1:service2
host2:service2
host3:service1
```

Now I want to be able to add a new host:service to the list (I've already done this by adding the new data at the end of the text file then that will be included on the next check when php will read again line by line.
Now now, how can I remove a host:service from the file ?

I mean, after reading the file, the PHP will make something like this:

```
Host: Host1   |    Service: Service1   |  Status: Warning (this will depend on the HTTP request I will make)     (X)
Host: Host1   |    Service: Service2   |  Status: OK     (X)
Host: Host3   |    Service: Service1   |  Status: Critical     (X)
```

I want to be able to remove a host:service from the list (and the file) just by clicking that (X). Is this possible guys? I'm a bit lost ( It will be easy for me to work with database but I can't on this project).

I hope I will get something clear.
Thanks in advance,
Regards.

Comment: You can't use a database because: You don't know how? They are against your religion? Why? Databases are "files" and so are file based. There are txt file based database systems for php and there is SQLITE.

Comment: @CaptainPayalytic: It's because this has to do local checks and I can't install a SQL server on the host. I have a portable PHP soft to run it (as I'm not good on JS).

Comment: As I just said, there are txt based database systems for php (http://www.c-worker.ch/txtdbapi/manual_html_eng/) and SQLITE writes to local files (you specify the pathe in the open statement). So you have NO reason why you cannot use a database!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP you want to do something like this:

**Code**

```
$string = 'host1:service1
host1:service2
host2:service2
host3:service1';

$splitted = explode("\n", $string);

$data = array();

foreach ($splitted as $key => $value) {
    $data[$key] = explode(':', $value);
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($data);
echo '<pre>';
```

You now have structured data you can do checks with if certain values match or are specific categories. The control over the output is now fully in your hands.

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => host1
            [1] => service1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => host1
            [1] => service2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => host2
            [1] => service2
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => host3
            [1] => service1
        )

)
```

If you still have issues outputting your data, feel free to ask in a comment and I'll update the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much. I already have something like this but instead of having one string I read the file line by line and then explode by ":" ((Edit: Sorry I wanted to add a new line but I saved)) My problem is that I want to save back the things so how do I know which one of the arrays I have deleted or how many new there are ? I mean if I delete array[2] but I add 5 new how do I know that it should loop 7 more times? I think I'm not very clear on this but if you don't understand please let me know.

Comment: Fairly simple; you can read the contents of the file into the string like so; `$string = file_get_contents('filename.txt')`. With that you have the exact same thing as the string in my answer. If you need to recheck the arrays length you can do a `count($array)` check inside the loop so you can determine what to do next, or even break the loop if required `break;`. If you want to mirror an old array (stored in a SESSION for example) to the array forged from a new file you need to mirror both arrays. Reference: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php :)

Answer (score 1):

Roughly:

1) Do an explode on the enters in the textfile so that you have a numbered array.

2) set an id for each line in the html (integer for each line number)

3) make a jquery function that has a "click" listener

4) create an AJAX script that has the integer as input

5) read the hosts.txt again, remove the line which corresponds with the number (unset($array['linenumber']))

6) implode with enters, write to file (overwriting the old one)

7) reload page (or hide the row)